# Incoming SSH works, but all outgoing fails

Tags: networking, debian, internet

## Terminology

I have a server (I'll refer to it as `S1` ) running in the cloud, but it is misbehaving. I also have another server (`S2`) running in the same cloud network, connected to `S1` through a separate network (`eth1`).

Server `S1` is connected to that internal network through `eth1`, and directly connected to the web through `eth0`.

`S1` is running Debian Jessie, upgraded from a clean Debian Wheezy by changing `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

`S2`, which works perfectly, is running Debian Wheezy. The same clean Debian Wheezy as `S1` before the upgrade.

## Situation

- I can connect to `S1` through SSH from outside the network

  - through interface `eth0`.
- I can connect to `S1` through SSH from another server (`S2`)

  - through interface `eth1`.
- I can connect from `S1` to the other server (`S2`)

  - through interface `eth1`.
- I can **not** connect from `S1` to the outside world

  - not through `eth0`
  - not through `eth1`
  - I cannot SSH to other servers; I cannot ping `8.8.8.8` (whilst `S2` *can*); I cannot resolve hosts (using `8.8.8.8` in  `/etc/resolv.conf`)

## Problem and Attempts

I haven't got the strangest idea as to why I can't connect to the outside world.

### iptables

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

### resolv.conf

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.147.234.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

### interfaces

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The one directly connected to the web
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The one connected to the internal network
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

### Ping requests

```
$ ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from (MY_IP) eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From (MY_IP) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From (MY_IP) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From (MY_IP) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

$ ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from (INTERNAL_IP) eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From (INTERNAL_IP) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From (INTERNAL_IP) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From (INTERNAL_IP) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

### route -n

```
$ route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.147.234.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0  eth1
(SUBNET_MY_IP (ends 0))    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 85.222.226.153  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

### ip_forward

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
```

### ifconfig -a

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:d9:ab:b0  
      inet addr:(MY_IP)  Bcast:(MY_IP_BUT_ENDS_WITH_255)  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: (MY_v6_IP) Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:75300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:689 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:9905366 (9.4 MiB)  TX bytes:86792 (84.7 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:2c:d7:80  
      inet addr:10.147.234.6  Bcast:10.147.234.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: (MY_INTERNAL_6_IP) Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:11626 (11.3 KiB)  TX bytes:1346 (1.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:22168 (21.6 KiB)  TX bytes:22168 (21.6 KiB)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ICMP request results you have problem with routing, show us:
`route -n`, `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and `ifconfig -a`.

After update: You don't have default route in route table, you can add it by:
`route add default gw x.x.x.x`, you should compare your results with working machine and search for row containing:
`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface`
`0.0.0.0         x.x.x.x        0.0.0.0          UG    1024   0        0 eth0`

As [qasdfdsaq](https://serverfault.com/users/287954/qasdfdsaq) correctly pointed it's not persistent solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thank you Michal. @peterh: It provides a partial answer; he answered the question "idk where to look". Anyhow, I have updated the original post.

Comment: Although route add default gw adds a default gateway, it doesn't solve why the machine isn't getting a default gateway in the first place, and more importantly, isn't persistent across reboots.

Comment: IMHO OP cannot do much with it because `/etc/network/interfaces` is configured correctly, it's task for VPS provider. Debugging DHCP is another site of the thread.

Comment: Fixing it once actually did manage to fix it across reboots. Not sure why, but it worked. (rebooting did not help before)